# I Have my wallet address but don’t know which wallet app to look for my NFT in. What do I do?

Tags: metamask

I need help please. I have my address and I can see my transactions on Etherscan but I can’t retrieve my NFTs. Rather I’m unfamiliar with the process. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily observe your NFTs via Metamask portfolio.

[image]

Then, click on NFTs tab, it will show all of the available NFTs in your wallet.

Comment: I don’t see it. I have a wallet address that’s linked to my personal NFTs. Rare pictures I minted of myself now I can’t see any of them. I had crypto punks that I can’t see anymore. I have the wallet address put it’s not popping up on meta mask.

Comment: An easier way to check is go to the blockchain scan to look for your NFTs. For example, your address is 0xfc82416000ba248684a4f7b9fbb56a17dbb72c3e, you have nft in Ethereum chain => you can go to this link to see: https://etherscan.io/address/0xfc82416000ba248684a4f7b9fbb56a17dbb72c3e#nfttransfers. If it has transactions, that means you have NFTs. If not, I believe you transfer your NFTs to the wrong address, or something weird happens.

Comment: Thank you bro I’ll try it out. But I know I didn’t transfer it or anything I see my wallet with a balance. And it’s on the polygon etherium network. 0xe178… that’s the first sequence of my address, how would I find which wallet it’s in?

Comment: I not only have transactions I have a wallet and I bought rare Cryptopunks about 2 years ago but I don’t see them at all on the same address that I see my other NFTs